# Как сделать вращение камеры вокруг объекта по движению мыши?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Камера прикреплена к объекту. Через RotateArround не получается.

```
float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
```

Вот всё что есть дальше не знаю как. Я уже по всякому пробовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

public float yMinLimit = -20f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

public float distanceMin = .5f;
public float distanceMax = 15f;

private void LateUpdate()
{
        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"), distanceMin, distanceMax);

        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        mouseY = ClampAngle(mouseY, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit, 7/*дальность вроде*/, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide))
        {
            distance -= hit.distance;
        }
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position + _offset;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
}
```

Вот поворот камеры вокруг объекта плюс ограничение дальности(мне лень было удалять из кода)

Comment: Спасибо, а почему в LateUpdate? Или не обязательно?

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков обычно в нем операции с камерой выполняются